# How can I monitor multiple sensors on Android?

Tags: java, android

Basic idea: I would like to monitor the gyroscope and the accelerometer at the same time.

```
private SensorManager mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
private Sensor mAccSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
private Sensor mGyroSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mGyroSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) {

        mGyroValues = event.values.clone();

        float x = mGyroValues[0];
        float y = mGyroValues[1];
        float z = mGyroValues[2];

        if (Math.abs(x) > 0.2 || Math.abs(y) > 0.2 || Math.abs(z) > 0.2) {
            deviceStatus.setText("Your device IS moving");
        } else {
            deviceStatus.setText("Your device IS NOT moving");
        }

    } else if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {

        mAccValues = event.values.clone();

        float x = mAccValues[0];
        float y = mAccValues[1];
        float z = mAccValues[2];
        mAccelLast = mAccelCurrent;
        mAccelCurrent = FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z);
        float delta = mAccelCurrent - mAccelLast;
        mAccel = mAccel * 1.0f + delta;

        if (mAccel > 0.2) {
            deviceStatus.setText("Your device IS moving");
        } else {
            deviceStatus.setText("Your device IS NOT moving");
        }
    }
```

Theoretically, this should make the `deviceStatus` (just a TextView) have the text `"Your device IS moving"` anytime I pick up the phone (via accelerometer data) OR anytime I spin it while it is laying down on the table (via gyroscope data).

However, it does not appear to be changing the text when I spin it on the table. I am outputting the various sensor data to other TextViews so I can confirm that both sensors are sending out data. It just seems to me that only my accelerometer code is executing correctly. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure about those `if (Math.abs(x) > 0.2 || Math.abs(y) > 0.2 || Math.abs(z) > 0.2) {`? Have you at least checked that this test is executed?

Comment: @njzk2 yeah I've added Log.d() statements and have tested those, the code definitely gets there...but the setText() doesn't seem to execute

Comment: also, the `0.2`'s are there so that slight variances from the gyroscope are accounted for ie higher numbers = less sensitive

Comment: and what values do you log for `x`, `y` and `z`?

Comment: @njzk2 depending on how hard I spin the device, I get anywhere from `0.01` to `3.00+`, so it should be enough to trigger

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger? Set a breakpoint and look if it stops in the if statement. Maybe the sensor change is too fast.

Comment: @codemonkey I think you might be right...because when I step through it while debugging it seems to go into that line. Would this mean the sensor update data is too fast? How can I rectify this?

Comment: there is a good chance that you are receiving several values, from both sensor, and the last one you receive is setting the text to false (the fact that you are spinning does not mean the accel sensor is not active as well)

Comment: Looks like that the text `Your device IS moving` is printed only a very short time so that you can not see it. You could use a marker to check if the threshold is reached. After a time reset the marker. It's a kind of debouncing

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys! Looks like @codemonkey was right, it was just updating WAY too fast and I need to add a way to slow it down.